# Why is there additional backslash shown in Postman and Django API Framework while in my database it does not have?

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman

In postman
[image]

Running API on web
[image]

SQL database

[image]

The intended way I wanted is properly stored in SQL database. I am trying to understand why is it shown differently.
For Postman, my combinedparameters value is

```
{'device': 202, 'configuration': {'port_range': 'TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1,TenGigabitEthernet2/0/2', 'port_mode': 'Access', 'port_status': 'Enabled', 'port_param1': '1\\n2\\n3', 'port_param2': '1\\n2\\n2'}}
```

But the output has `\\\\` instead of `\\`

Comment: Maybe irrelevant to OP - What is `\\n`? Shouldn't it be `\n` in the first place?

Comment: To be honest, the intended way was ```\n```. But when i convert it to a dict in django views, there was a additional backslash added. And according to one of the people here, " automatically escapes backslash:) It's a safety practice:) ". Or is there some way to remove the additional backslash?